Wix toolset: How to just edit a config file on upprade
I have a Wix installer that installs a certain application.
I am new to the Wix toolset and have difficulties changing only one tag in my config file on an upgrade (while completely setting all tags to default on a fresh installation).
This is my Files.wsx file, I am trying to achieve the following behavior:

On fresh install: set test_value_path to the value of
[TEST_VALUE_PATH]

On upgrade, just stay with the current value that it has in the file.


   <Component Directory="certificates">
     <File Id="test_upgrade.pem" Source="$(var.testCertificatesDir)test_upgrade.pem" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
   </Component>

   <Component Directory="Config">
     <File Source="$(var.testConfigDir)My_App.xml" KeyPath="yes" />
     <RemoveFile Id="My_App.xml" Name="My_App.xml" On="both"/>
     <util:XmlFile Id="tets_log_level" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/config/tets_log_level" Value="[TEST_LOG_LEVEL]" File="[#My_App.xml]" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Permanent="yes"/>
     <util:XmlFile Id="tets_log_path" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/config/tets_log_path" Value="[TEST_LOG_PATH]" File="[#My_App.xml]" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Permanent="yes"/>
     <util:XmlFile Id="test_value_path" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/config/test_value_path" Value="[TEST_VALUE_PATH]" File="[#My_App.xml]" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Permanent="yes"/>
   </Component>
 </ComponentGroup>



